java.lang.NullPointerException trying to use Page Objects with Appium and TestNG
I am trying to write a basic test with Appium and TestNG using Browserstack. I am trying to add Page Objects but when I try to construct the page object I keep getting a Null Pointer Exception.
Config:
public class BrowserStackConfig {
    protected AppiumDriver<MobileElement> appiumDriver;

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    @Parameters("platform")
    public void setUp(String platform, ITestResult testMethod) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> config = readConfigFromFile();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        ConfigReader reader = new ConfigReader();

        String device;
        String os;
        String app;

        switch (platform) {
            case "android":
                app = (String) config.get("androidApp");
                device = (String) config.get("androidDevice");
                os = (String) config.get("androidVersion");
                break;
            case "ios":
                device = (String) config.get("iOSDevice");
                os = (String) config.get("iOSVersion");
                app = (String) config.get("iosApp");
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported OS: " + platform);
        }

        capabilities.setCapability("device", device);
        capabilities.setCapability("os_version", os);
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", platform);
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);
        capabilities.setCapability("idleTimeout", "1000");
        capabilities.setCapability("settings[enableMultiWindows]", true);

        String url = reader.urlBrowserStack(testMethod);

        if ("android".equals(platform)) {
            appiumDriver = new AppiumDriver<>(new URL(url), capabilities);
        } else {
            appiumDriver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL(url), capabilities);
        }
    }

    private Map<String, Object> readConfigFromFile() throws IOException {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("browserstack.yml")) {
            return yaml.load(fileReader);
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown(ITestResult testResult) throws Exception {
        ResultsListener result = new ResultsListener(appiumDriver);
        if (ITestResult.SUCCESS == testResult.getStatus()) {
            result.passResult(appiumDriver);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } else {
            result.failResult(appiumDriver);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
        appiumDriver.quit();
    }
}


BasePage:
public class BasePage extends BrowserStackConfig{

    protected AppiumDriver<MobileElement> appiumDriver; 

    public BasePage (AppiumDriver<MobileElement> appiumDriver) {
        appiumDriver = this.appiumDriver;
    }
    
}

LandingPage:
public class LandingPage extends BasePage {

    public LandingPage(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> appiumDriver) {
        super(appiumDriver);
    }

    // Element locators
    private AndroidElement  logInBtn = (AndroidElement ) new WebDriverWait(appiumDriver, 10).until(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(MobileBy.id(
            "button_log_in"
        ))
    );

    // Methods
    public boolean isInitialized() {
        try {
            return logInBtn.isDisplayed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

and AppTest
public class AppTest extends BrowserStackConfig {

    private final SoftAssert assertion = new SoftAssert();

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage(appiumDriver);

        // assert landing page is loaded
        assertion.assertTrue(landingPage.isInitialized());
    }
}

When I run the tests, I get
AppTest.test » NullPointer for the line LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage(appiumDriver);
I have tried every combination I can find of initializing and constructing the page objects but I keep getting the NPE whenever I try to construct a page.

Figured it out, posting answer for posterity
one important word: protected
variable appiumDriver was protected in the BrowserStackConfig, so when I tried to pass it to the landingPage to create the Page Object, it was receiving null. Changing the first line to public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> appiumDriver; fixed the issue.
(Also, BasePage should not have been extending BrowserStackConfig)
